# What is the easiest way to merge a lot of objects and then get only the outer shell?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

So for 3D print of my character, I need to merge all the parts together. And there is a lot of them. There is a sword, mechanical parts, body, clothes, hair...

What is the easiest way to merge all that?

The problem isn't just merging. It's also getting only the outer shell of a character. Since there can't be any parts on the inside.

I am really lost and need this figured out soon. :( Thanks in advance.